# Testing if a polynomial has roots within a radius/range

Tags: polynomials, roots

Is there a way to test if a high-order polynomials has any roots within a radius r of a specified point?

I need this so that I can find all the complex roots of the following system for arbitrary integers {m,n}.

$$z_0 \equiv c$$
$$z_n \equiv z_{n-1}^2 + c $$
$$z_m - z_n = 0$$
$$|c-i|<r$$

I can generate a large polynomial like $z_{20}-z_8$, calculate a root near i, divide it out of the polynomial, repeat...  But then I need to know when there are no more roots in that radius so I can stop looking.  Does such a test exist?  Efficient root-finding is important because the polynomial orders scale as $2^n$.

As a side note, these points are called [Misiurewicz points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576073/an-interesting-way-to-visualize-the-mandelbrot-set-proofs-simplifications-ext)

Answer (score 0):

One easily proven result: If we put $P(z)=P(z_0)+\sum_{j=1}^n A_j(z-z_0)^j,$ with $A_n=1,$ then $$P(z)=0\implies |z-z_0|<1+M$$ where    $M=\max (\{|P(z_0)|\}\cup \{|A_j| :1\leq j<n\})......$     For example if $P(z)=A+B z+C z^2 +  D z^3 +z^4$ with $M=\max (A,B,C,D),$ if $|z|\geq 1+M$ then $P(z)\geq |z|^4-M(1+|z|+|z|^2+|z|^3)=$ $=|z|^4-M(|z|^4-1)/(|z|-1)=(|z|^4(|z|-1-M)+M)/(|z|-1)>0.$ When using this, a change of scale, $z=k x$ with constant $k,$ is sometimes helpful.

Comment: But that still leaves me needing to find all the roots to be sure I got all the ones in the range--or it leaves me doing a calculation that's equally expensive.