# How to find Misiurewicz Points without solving huge polynomials? (Mandelbrot Set)

Tags: recreational-mathematics, fractals

Here is a plot of 17,723 Misiurewicz Points. The code below generates a set of polynomials u[m,n], the roots of which have periodicity (m-n) starting at iteration n.  I stopped at 17,723 points because to get more by this method I had to generate and solve $2^{11}$-order polynomials.  In other words, I hit the practical limit of my method.

[image: Misi17723]

So my question is: Is there any way I can find more Misiurewicz points without having to solve giant polynomials?

This relates to another [Question about the right-most real Misiurewicz Point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639640/where-does-the-series-of-real-mandelbrot-lobes-end-rightmost-real-misiurewicz).

Mathematica code:

```
z[n_, c_] := If[n > 0, z[n - 1, c]^2 + c, c];
ord = 8;
(* Calculate u[m,n] up to m==ord *)
Do[Do[
   If[n > 0, t = Expand[z[m, c] - z[n, c]], t = Expand[z[m - 1, c]]];
   p = m - n;
   Do[Do[If[((i != m) || (j != n)) && (Mod[p, i - j] == 0),
      While[(tt = PolynomialQuotientRemainder[t, u[i, j], c])[[2]] == 0, t = tt[[1]]]], {j, 0, Min[n, i - 1]}], {i, 1, m}];
   u[m, n] = t, {n, 0, m - 1}], {m, 1, ord}];
Print["Polynomial orders : ", Table[Exponent[u[m, n], c], {m, 1, ord}, {n, 0, m - 1}] // MatrixForm];

(* Compile numerical roots of u[m,n>0], which are c's on the edge of the M-set *)
plotOrd = 8;
$MaxRootDegree = Max[$MaxRootDegree, 2^(plotOrd - 1)];
rts = {};
Do[
  Do[
   s[m, n] = Solve[u[m, n] == 0, c] // N;
   rts = Append[rts, c /. s[m, n]], {n, 1, m - 1}], {m, 1, plotOrd}];
rts = Flatten[rts];
Print["Number of Plot points : ", Length[rts]];
Print[ListPlot[Transpose[{Re[rts], Im[rts]}],PlotStyle ->PointSize[Small]]];
```

These settings will produce a plot in few seconds.  The jpeg above took a while and was generated with

```
ord=11;
plotOrd=11;
```

and

```
Print[ListPlot[Transpose[{Re[rts], Im[rts]}],PlotStyle ->PointSize[Tiny]]];
```

Comment: The parabolic and Misiurewicz points can be parametrized by the rational numbers between 0 and 1 using the idea of an *external ray*. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_ray) provides a serviceable introduction, [this paper](http://goo.gl/7w6erY) provides a modern account, and [Milnor's book](http://goo.gl/EpM8qF) is excellent as well. External rays are not hard to compute and you can use one to get close to a Misiurewicz point. I could provide more details over on [Mathematica.se](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/), if you like.

Comment: @MarkMcClure  Thanks, that would be great.  But I think it would be kosher to post MMa code here, since it's the answer to a math question.

Comment: @MarkMcClure paper link has rotted.  Archive copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20170519212111/http://dynamics.user.jacobs-university.de/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/DouadyPaper2015_red.pdf *Rational Parameter Rays Of The Mandelbrot Set* Dierk Schleicher

Comment: @MarkMcClure book link has rotted. *Dynamics in One Complex Variable: Introductory Lectures* John Milnor (2nd Ed, 2000)

Answer (score 0):

Using numerical methods, like:

1. [Misiurewicz domains](http://mathr.co.uk/blog/2015-02-01_misiurewicz_domains.html)
2. [Newton's method for Misiurewicz points](http://mathr.co.uk/blog/2015-01-26_newtons_method_for_misiurewicz_points.html)